# How do I import the FRC WPILib library into ROS Noetic and use it in a project?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, robotics

I am currently working on a robot project using the VMX-Pi by Kauai Labs. The OS that we are using on the raspberry pi is provided by Studica as a specialised ROS image(https://docs.wsr.studica.com/en/latest/docs/ROS/GettingStarted/installing-ros.html). The ROS version is ROS Noetic. I am currently trying to incorporate a trapezoidal profile movement onto my robot. I plan to achieve this by importing the FRC WPILib libraries into ROS and using the trapezoidal profile class.

I have tried cloning the libraries off github into a ROS package and editing the CMake files yet I always face errors when building. I need to know the way to properly import these libraries into ROS and use them in a project. Thanks.